# Won't add Textbox values to DataGridView using Parameters when the button is clicked

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am working with Visual Basic 2008 and the issue is I want to pass text box values to a `DataGridView` using `Parameters`. But whenever I debug my application and click the save button the form shows but the `DataGridView` stays blank.

This is my code so far:

```
Public Class frmEncode

Dim strConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & System.Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\EncodingComplete.accdb"

Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
Dim cmdOLEDB As New OleDbCommand
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
  Private Sub ButtonX10_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles     ButtonX10.Click

    Dim InsertQuery As String

    InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO EncodingComplete (Client, NoxiousRate, Address, Date_Bill, BusStyle_Name, Vessel, TIN, Port, [Pier No], InterPleader1, InterPleader2, Call_Date, Call_Time, Call_VoyageNo, FixedFee_Total, Call_ReceiveBy, VesselType, VesselCalls, FixedFee_ExcessCum, FixedFee_Amount, FixedFee_Rate, GarbageExcessCum, GarbageRate, GarbageAmnt, GarbageTotal, NoxiousExcessCum, NoxiousAmnt, NoxiousTotal, OtherExcessCum, OtherRate, OtherAmnt, OtherTotal, DollarConvers, AmountDue, PaymentDetails, TypeofPayment, DateofPayment, OrNo, Amount, Collector, BI, CSR, Other, OilyExcessCum, OilyRate, OilyAmnt, OilyTotal )VALUES(@client, @nRate, @address, @date, @buss, @vess, @tin, @port, @pier, @intpl1, @intpl2, @cDate, @cTime, @cVoy, @fFeeTotal, @cRec, @VessType, @vCalls, @fFee_ExcessCum, @fFee_Amnt, @fFee_Rate, @gExcessCum, @gRate, @gAmnt, @gTotal, @nExcessCum, @nAmnt, @nTotal, @oExcessCum, @oRate, @oAmnt, @oTotal, @dol, @due, @paydetails, @paytype, @datepay, @orno, @amnt, @col, @bi, @csr, @o, @oilexcesscum, @oilrate, @oilamnt, @oilTotal)"

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(InsertQuery, cnnOLEDB)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client", ComboBoxEx1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nRate", TextBoxX28.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBoxX1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTimePicker1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@buss", TextBoxX11.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vess", TextBoxX2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tin", TextBoxX3.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@port", ComboBoxEx2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pier", TextBoxX12.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intpl1", ComboBoxEx4.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intpl2", ComboBoxEx5.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cDate", TextBoxX6.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cTime", TextBoxX9.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cVoy", TextBoxX4.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fFeeTotal", TextBoxX49.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cRec", TextBoxX10.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VessType", ComboBoxEx3.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vCalls", ComboBoxEx8.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fFee_ExcessCum", TextBoxX14.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fFee_Amnt", TextBoxX40.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fFee_Rate", TextBoxX31.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gExcessCum", TextBoxX15.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gRate", TextBoxX30.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gAmnt", TextBoxX39.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gTotal", TextBoxX48.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nExcessCum", TextBoxX17.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nAmnt", TextBoxX37.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nTotal", TextBoxX46.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oExcessCum", TextBoxX18.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oRate", TextBoxX8.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oAmnt", TextBoxX36.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oTotal", TextBoxX45.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dol", TextBoxX50.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@due", TextBoxX51.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paydetails", TextBoxX52.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paytype", ComboBoxEx7.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datepay", TextBoxX53.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orno", TextBoxX54.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amnt", TextBoxX55.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col", TextBoxX56.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bi", TextBoxX7.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@csr", TextBoxX5.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@o", TextBoxX13.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oilexcesscum", TextBoxX16.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oilrate", TextBoxX29.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oilamnt", TextBoxX38.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oilTotal", TextBoxX47.Text)
    cnnOLEDB.Open()
    cmdOLEDB = New OleDbCommand(InsertQuery, cnnOLEDB)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cnnOLEDB.Close()
    frmEncodeDatabase.Show()
```

Comment: This will *never* work. You cannot *"pass textbox values to a datagridview using parameters"*. The`Insert` clause returns the number of affected rows. If you want to *select* rows from your database then use the `Select` clause - then use a data adapter or execute the command as a reader.

Comment: Will the codes here work? http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/286791-passing-data-from-textbox-to-datagridview/

Answer (score 0):

```
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

should be

```
 cmdOLEDB.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Sorry sir...I changed my post because it is already solved. I have only one problem sir which is already in the post. The problem before is I have some missing values.

Comment: where is the code for filling datagridview.There is no such code snippet in you question..

Comment: I drag the DataGridView from data sources to the form.. No need such crazy coding. You can deal it with the properties (Data Source).